# How to deal with filenames containing a single quote inside a zsh completion function?

Tags: zsh, quoting, autocomplete

I'm using the `zsh` shell and have the following code inside my `.zshrc`:

```
fpath=(~/.zsh/completion $fpath)
autoload -Uz _vc

autoload -Uz compinit
compinit
```

The first line add the path `~/.zsh/completion` to the array stored inside the environment variable `fpath`.

The 2nd line loads a completion function, called `_vc`, for a custom shell function called `vc`. The purpose of `vc` is simply to edit a file inside a particular folder (`~/.cheat`). `_vc` is defined in the file `~/.zsh/completion/_vc`.

The last 2 lines enable a completion system.

Here's the code for my completion function `_vc`:

```
#compdef vc

declare -a cheatsheets
cheatsheets="$(ls ~/.cheat)"
_arguments "1:cheatsheets:(${cheatsheets})" && return 0
```

I copied it from this [address](https://github.com/chrisallenlane/cheat/blob/master/cheat/autocompletion/cheat.zsh), and adapted it for my needs.

As long as the directory `~/.cheat` doesn't have a file whose name contains a single quote, the completion works. But if there's one, such as `foo'bar`, the completion fails with this error message:

```
(eval):56: unmatched '
(eval):56: unmatched '
(eval):56: unmatched '
(eval):56: unmatched '
```

I found a solution, by replacing the double quotes in the line `cheatsheets="$(ls ~/.cheat)"`, with single quotes `cheatsheets='$(ls ~/.cheat)'`.

Now, when I hit `Tab` after my `vc` command, zsh suggests files inside `~/.cheat`, including `foo\'bar` (zsh seems to have escaped the single quote automatically).

However, I don't understand how or why it works. With single quotes, the variable `cheatsheets` sould contain a literal string. So the `$(...)` command substitution shouldn't be expanded. For example, if I execute the following commands:

```
myvar='$(ls)'
echo $myvar    →    outputs `$(ls)` literally
```

So why is `'$(ls ~/.cheat)'` expanded inside `_arguments "1:cheatsheets:(${cheatsheets})" && return 0`? And why does it automatically escape the single quote inside `foo'bar`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If we insist on doing things The Wrong Way™

```
#compdef vc

declare -a cheatsheets
cheatsheets=(${(f)"$(ls ~/.cheat/)"})
_arguments '1:cheatsheets:(${cheatsheets})' && return 0
```

Yuck! This of course will break should a filename contain a newline, as `(f)` splits on those. [Parsing `ls` is anyways a bad idea](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/128985/why-not-parse-ls); ZSH can glob files directly into an array:

```
% mkdir ~/.lojban
% touch ~/.lojban/{go\'i,na\ go\'i}
% words=(~/.lojban/*) 
% print -l ${words:t}
go'i
na go'i
% words=(~/.lojban/*(On))
% print -l ${words:t}    
na go'i
go'i
%
```

But we probably don't need a local array; `_files` can complete on a glob:

```
#compdef vc
_arguments '1:cheatsheets:_files -g "~/.cheat/*"' && return 0
```

This returns fully qualified file paths; if only the bare filename is required from a search directory we can instead use:

```
#compdef vc
_arguments '1:cheatsheets:_files -W ~/.cheat' && return 0
```